# AnalysisException: No matching function with signature: rtrim(VARCHAR(40), STRING)

Tags: python, sql, oracle, hive, impala

I have the value of 58.3308% in the table(include % character), I need output of 0.583308, and the SQL query as below works fine in SQL console

```
select to_char((rtrim('58.3308%', '%') /100), '0.999999') from dual;
```

But I get this error in my python code, it's a hive/impala problem, right?

> AnalysisException: No matching function with signature: rtrim(VARCHAR(40), STRING)

Thanks so much for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Hive manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF), rtrim only removes whitespaces and thus does not take a second parameter. If you want to remove other characters, consider using regexp_replace as in `regexp_replace('58.3308%', '%', '')`

As per documentation:

> rtrim(string A)
>
> Returns the string resulting from trimming spaces from the end(right
> hand side) of A. For example, rtrim(' foobar ') results in ' foobar'.

and

> regexp_replace(string INITIAL_STRING, string PATTERN, string
> REPLACEMENT)
>
> Returns the string resulting from replacing all substrings in
> INITIAL_STRING that match the java regular expression syntax defined
> in PATTERN with instances of REPLACEMENT. For example,
> regexp_replace("foobar", "oo|ar", "") returns 'fb.' Note that some
> care is necessary in using predefined character classes: using '\s' as
> the second argument will match the letter s; '\s' is necessary to
> match whitespace, etc.

By the way, the result of this operation will be a string, so you should cast it to float just to be safe.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice, use this `cast(regexp_replace('58.3308%', '%%', '') as decimal(20,8))*0.01`, it works fine now, ☕️

Answer (score 0):

You could use `split`

```
select split('58.3308%', '%')[0] /100 as v
+--------+
|       v|
+--------+
|0.583308|
+--------+
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the answer, I got an error of `AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 2:
...e, split('58.3308%', '%')[0]/100 as val
                             ^
Encountered: [
Expected: AND, AS, ASC, BETWEEN, BLOCK_SIZE, COMMENT, COMPRESSION, CROSS, DEFAULT, DESC, DIV, ELSE, ENCODING, END, FOLLOWING, FROM, FULL, GROUP, IGNORE, HAVING, ILIKE, IN, INNER, IREGEXP, IS, JOIN.............

CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

unable to rollback`